# on my first steps with tensorflow, it seems like Model has no training

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I do my fist steps with tensorflow in JavaScript... I think it should train the network, but the rendering is a straight line only...

```
        var model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units : 10, inputShape : [1], activation : 'sigmoid'}));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units : 10, activation : 'sigmoid'}));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units : 1, outputShape : [1], activation : 'sigmoid'}));
        model.compile({optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.000001),loss: 'meanSquaredError'});
        model.fit(xTrain,yTrain,{epochs : 300,verbose : true});
        var yP = model.predict(xPredict,{epochs : 300,verbose : true});

        window.setInterval(function() {
            render();
        },100);
```

Comment: 3 test data entries are really few

Comment: xTrain.size == 1000 and yTrain.size == 1000